# Porting Django's templates engine to C

Tags: python, c, django, templates, django-templates

I recently wrote a simple and tiny embedded HTTP server for my C++ app (QT) and I played a little bit with [Ry's http-parser](http://github.com/ry/http-parser) and *loved* it. This guy is *crazy*.

So I told to myself: "Hey! Why not port the django template engine to C?" That'd be awesome! 
I know, it won't be an easy task (not at all, I know) but I'd really love to implement this. So I came here for inspiration, ideas, opinions...

I'd really love to have some pointers on the subject, ideas, what is already done, which major problems I'll encounter (and how to solve them) - How not to reinvent the wheel... anyway, you got the idea :)

Thanks a million times!

P.S. Simple code snippets, and links to tools and libs are *very* welcome!

P.P.S. I'm already aware of [grantlee](http://github.com/ry/http-parser), I took a look into its sources. Well... that's C++ and it's specific to Qt.

Comment: I just found this http://github.com/panyam/mango maybe, it will help? I still don't know what it's all about but I'm reading the sources

Comment: It's about porting django templates to erlang, but at least it's about porting this particular project: [Write A Template Compiler For Erlang](http://www.evanmiller.org/write-a-template-compiler-for-erlang.html)

Comment: Thank you, @The MYYN! I think I got the idea, the article is very nice indeed!

Comment: Are you still working on this? I'd be interested in seeing what you came up with and using it as a starting point pretty soon. I've got a couple things in use right now, like a couple simple POSIX regexs in ctypes to do the most common operations for me. It's proven to be faster when looping large amounts of replacements without leaving cpp.

Comment: Any update on this project two and a half years after the post?

Answer (score 6):

Hmm, I don't see why anything in the django templates code would be hard to implement in C.  The template syntax looks a bit pythonic, but it's not actually python; they implemented their own parser for it.  So the first place to look would be the [django template implementation in python](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template).  It's really not much code, and it's reasonably easy to understand.

Of course, C will be much more verbose.  What you're writing is exactly a compiler: it reads in some code (the django templates) and writes out some code in another language (the html).  So all the documentation you can find about writing compilers in C (ie. tokenizers + parsers + code generators) is relevant.

First you'll probably want to generate a syntax tree.  The syntax of django templates is very regular... every `{% whatever %}` block has a corresponding `{% endwhatever %}` block, so your parser could actually generate the tree without actually knowing what all the `whatever` keywords might be.

Then, you walk through the tree, doing the "code gen" phase for each block.  For example, you'd codegen `{% if %}` by checking the value of the if parameter, and printing either its contents or nothing, depending whether the if clause is true or false.  And so on with while loops, filters, blocks, etc.

Mind you, all this is a lot of work... have you considered just embedding a python interpreter into your C program?  (Seriously!  It's not that hard to do, since the python interpreter is open source.)

Comment: Thank you, apenwarr! That's in fact what I'm doing right now. Writing a tokenizer first and then a parser for every token. and assemble the whole thing. That won't be easy and I have to find a nice way to declare and use Contexts of variables of different types. But that's fun anyway :)

Answer (score 5):

In case it is useful, the [Synth](https://github.com/ajg/synth/) framework features a complete stand-alone re-implementation of Django's template system in C++. It includes all [built-in tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) as well as support for custom ones; besides the library itself, there are Python bindings, in addition to a native command-line tool, which can read in data from arbitrary sources like JSON, INIs or XML.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, [onion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion/wiki) has a Django-link template system.

It compiles the template to C, and even allows a little bit of gdb debugging on them.

The code generated is quite onion oriented, but with some work it can be more generic.

Answer (score 1):

If you or anyone else is interested in a C++ implementation of the Django template engine, I am working on it: http://git.fawek.net/Cjango/. It's not ready yet though.

Comment: How does it handle custom template tags and filters?

Comment: TagNodeFactory and FilterFactory are the two interfaces that the client side would use to inject custom functionality. The former takes a factory function (for each tag name) that allocates an object of a TagNode subclass every time it is needed in the template tree. With the latter you just assign a Filter object to a given filter name.

Answer (score 0):

hello   why don't you use the official python binding for c++

you will be able to call python module and python script  throw you  c++ application

if you want to use this just include <python.h> in your application and link with  python32.DLL

when you install python on your computer python come with his c++ binding  by default
look at this image for more details

[where you can find lib include and dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiJds.jpg)

read the doc for more details or contact me

[use python in c++](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html)